# Upgrade N2CMS to latest version collected from github trunk

Tags: upgrade, n2, n2cms

I am upgrading an old N2CMS website to the newest version released in the trunk (2.2.5 or something like that), following these instructions https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/blob/master/docs/releases/upgrade_2.2.1.txt but i am getting an error when tring to compile the project:

*Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.*

Has anyone done this before and know if there's anything else i should be doing appart from just copying files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Complete text of this error contains the name of DLL you are missing. Read it carefully and you will find out what DLL you need to add. It could be something like Lucene.dll which was introduced recently (it depends how old your project is).